# Javascript/jQuery bug in my Trivia Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I am creating a basic Trivia Game for a Web Dev class.  We are to use HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery to create it.  The new element that we are to work with in this assignment are the setTimeout() & setInterval() methods.

After clicking the start button, the game will ask a question and offer 4 possible answers.  The user either clicks an answer or the timer runs out.  The results are displayed and then then the next questions auto-loads.  Once all of the questions in the questions array are asked, the game displays the overall results and then refreshes screen.

The bug that I discovered is that if I let the timer run all the way down until the "zero" is just displayed on the screen and then quickly click on an answer, it causes the game to react as if the conditions of an answer being clicked and the time running out had occurred simultaneously.  Then the next question loads too many answers and the timer is decrementing at an increased rate.  I'm not sure if there is some sort of time lag in the timer reaching zero somewhere that allows the answer clicks to transmit through and this creates a new timerID that doesn't get cleared which causes the time decrementing on the next question to increase in rate.

I've created a Fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/brianpatrickhummel/0a2hg782/

```
var correctAnswers = 0;
var incorrectAnswers = 0;
var unansweredQuestions = 0;
var timeRemaining = 16;
var intervalID;
var indexQandA = 0;    //index to load a different question each round without the game reset or screen refresh
var answered = false;  //variable to stop the timer if user has clicked an answer
var correct;
var triviaGame = [
        {question:"HOW MANY COLORS ARE THERE ON A RUBIK'S CUBE ?", answer:["5", "6", "7", "4"], correct: "1", image:("assets/images/rubik.png")},
        {question:"WHAT IS THE SPEED OF LIGHT ?", answer:["8,600 MILES per SECOND","86,000 MILES per SECOND","186,000 MILES per SECOND","886,000 MILES per SECOND"], correct:"2", image:("assets//images/lightspeed.jpg")},
        {question:"APPROXIMATELY HOW LONG DOES IT TAKE FOR SUNLIGHT TO REACH THE EARTH ?", answer:["45 SECONDS", "10 HOURS", "2 HOURS 15 MINUTES", "8 MINUTES"], correct:"3", image:("assets//images/sunlight.jpg")},
        {question:"WHAT ELEMENT'S CHEMICAL SYMBOL IS Pb ?", answer:["POTASSIUM","STRONTIUM","LEAD","PALLADIUM"], correct:"2", image:("assets//images/periodictable.png")},
        {question:"HOW FAST CAN BEES FLY ?", answer:["35 MPH", "15 MPH", "48 MPH", "8 MPH"], correct:"1", image: ("assets/images/bee.png")},
        {question:"WHAT IS THE MOST ABUNDANT ELEMENT IN THE UNIVERSE ?", answer:["HYDROGEN", "OXYGEN", "HELIUM", "CARBON"], correct:"0", image:("assets//images/universe.png")},
        {question:"THE AIR THAT WE BREATHE IS COMPRISED MOSTLY OF WHAT ELEMENT ?", answer:["CARBON", "ARGON", "OXYGEN", "NITROGEN"], correct:"3", image:("assets//images/breathe.jpg")},
        {question:"WHAT IS THE DIAMETER OF THE EARTH ?", answer:["140,000 MILES", "2,500,000 MILES", "8,000 MILES", "25,000,000 MILES"], correct:"2", image:("assets//images/earth.png")}   
];

// ------------- FUNCTION DECLARATIONS ----------------------------


function startGame() {
    console.log("game has begun");
    $('.start-button').remove();
    correctAnswers = 0;
    incorrectAnswers = 0;
    unansweredQuestions = 0;
    loadQandA ();
}       

function loadQandA() {
    // console.log(correctAnswers);
    // console.log(incorrectAnswers);
    // console.log(unansweredQuestions);
    // console.log(indexQandA);
    answered = false;    // will allow timeRemaining to be pushed back to <h5> after round reset....else statement in function timer()
    timeRemaining = 16;
    intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    if (answered === false){
        timer();
    }
    correct = triviaGame[indexQandA].correct;
    var question = triviaGame[indexQandA].question;
    $('.question').html(question);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var answer = triviaGame[indexQandA].answer[i];
        $('.answers').append('<h4 class= answersAll id=' + i + '>' + answer + '</h4>');
    }

    $( "h4" ).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        // alert(id);
        if (id === correct) {
            answered = true;    // stops the timer
            // alert("correct answer");
            $('.question').text("THE ANSWER IS: " + triviaGame[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
            correctAnswer ();
        }
        else {
            answered = true;    //stops the timer
            // alert("incorrect answer");
            $('.question').text("YOU CHOSE: " + triviaGame[indexQandA].answer[id] + ".....HOWEVER THE ANSWER IS: " + triviaGame[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
            incorrectAnswer();
        }
    });     
}

function timer() { 
    if (timeRemaining === 0) {
        answered = true;
        clearInterval(intervalID);  
        $('.question').text("THE CORRECT ANSWER IS: " + triviaGame[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
        unAnswered();
    }
    else if (answered === true) {
        clearInterval(intervalID); 
    }
    else {
        timeRemaining--;
        $('.timeRemaining').text('YOU HAVE ' + timeRemaining + ' SECONDS TO CHOOSE').removeClass('animated pulse infinite');
    }
}   

function correctAnswer() {
    correctAnswers++;
    $('.timeRemaining').text("YOU HAVE ANSWERED CORRECTLY!").css({'color':'#3D414F'}).addClass('animated pulse infinite');
    resetRound();
}

function incorrectAnswer() {
    incorrectAnswers++;
    $('.timeRemaining').text("YOU HAVE ANSWERED INCORRECTLY!").css({'color':'#3D414F'}).addClass('animated pulse infinite');
    resetRound();

}

function unAnswered() {
    unansweredQuestions++;
    $('.timeRemaining').text("YOU FAILED TO CHOOSE AN ANSWER").css({'color':'#3D414F'}).addClass('animated pulse infinite');
    resetRound();
}

function resetRound() {
    $('.answersAll').remove();
    $('.answers').append('<img class=answerImage src="' + triviaGame[indexQandA].image + ' ">');   // adds answer image
    indexQandA++;                                   // increments index which will load next question when loadQandA() is called again
    if (indexQandA < triviaGame.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){ loadQandA(); $('.answerImage').remove();}, 5000);         // removes answer image from previous round
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('.question').remove();
            $('.timeRemaining').remove();
            $('.answerImage').remove(); 
            $('.answers').append('<h4 class= answersAll end>CORRECT ANSWERS: ' + correctAnswers + '</h4>');
            $('.answers').append('<h4 class= answersAll end>INCORRECT ANSWERS: ' + incorrectAnswers + '</h4>');
            $('.answers').append('<h4 class= answersAll end>UNANSWERED QUESTIONS: ' + unansweredQuestions + '</h4>');
            setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 7000);    
        }, 5000);  
    }
}





// ----------------------- MAIN PROCESS ---------------------


$('.startButton').on("click", function() {
    $('.startButton').removeClass('infinite').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');   //manages the Animate.css applied to Start Button
        startGame();

});
```

Comment: The 2nd game I had all the answers right. What do I win?

Comment: The only place you call `clearInterval()` is inside your `timer` function, and it checks for 0 first, regardless whether there was an answer selected. The interval should be cleared as soon as an answer is selected.

Comment: Simply swapping the first two `if` conditions in the `timer` function makes it work, albeit it doesn't make the code less messy. ;) https://jsfiddle.net/0a2hg782/2/

Comment: I can't even imagine how disorderly, bloated and generally unsightly my code must look, being that I have no real frame of reference for judging such things as of yet.  I'm two months into one of these infamous bootcamps and am grateful that some of you have been kind enough to entertain my rudimentary inquiry.    DarthJDG-   thank you for your comments.

Comment: @BrianPatrickHummel Any time, keep up the good work. We've all been beginners once.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you establish a timer with either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, you need to set a variable to the returned timer id. That variable needs to have a high enough scope so that you can access it from any place where the timer must be interacted with.

Then, anywhere you need to interrupt the timer, you can clear it.  In your case, when an answer is clicked, you need to stop the countdown timer.

Here's a scaled down example:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
  var btnStart = document.getElementById("btnStart");
  var btnStop = document.getElementById("btnStop");
  
  // Declare this where you can get at it
  var timer1 = null;
  
  function start(){
    clock.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    timer1 = setTimeout(start, 900);
  }
  
  function stop(){
    // Cancel the timer
    clearTimeout(timer1);
  }
  
  btnStart.addEventListener("click", start);
  btnStop.addEventListener("click", stop);
  
  start();

});
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
<button id="btnStop">Stop the Clock</button>
<button id="btnStart">Start the Clock</button>
```